# Is it possible to display a robot model on top of the camera image in Rviz?

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, ros, rospy

I am trying to display a 3D model of my drone on an image it had taken earlier. I have transforms, camera_info, historical position data, and timestamps, as well as the URDF and the model. However, I cannot seem to get that image and the robotmodel to appear in the same [visualization frame].

Is it possible to show the camera image in the same [visualization frame] as robotmodel, TF, and markers? This might allow for the ability to skew the image to represent its state when it was taken. Or, alternatively, can I display the robotmodel on the Camera frame?